# How to use std::find on a custom object inside a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, find, std

Trying to use `std::find` on a vector that contains custom objects
but I can't figure out how to use it to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Is there another way to do this type of thing?

```
struct object
{
    char x;
    int y;
    object(char x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<object> vector;

    object obj = object('X', 0);

    vector.push_back(obj);

    if (std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), ? ? ? ) != vector.end())
    {
        //do something
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to find `obj.y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm has multiple version, some of which you can define a way to compare elements. By default, it will simply use equality comparison `==`.

```
//         v----- found is not a boolean, but an iterator
auto const found = std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), element_to_find);
```

If equality is not enough, then you could use `std::find_if` which accepts a predicate to compare elements:

```
auto const predicate = 
    [&](auto const& element) {
        return element.is_the_one(); // element.is_the_one() returns a boolean
                                     // You can use obj.y here
    };

//         v----- found is not a boolean, but an iterator
auto const found = std::find_if(vector.begin(), vector.end(), predicate);
```

I'd recommend reading the documentation in order to know how to handle the return value if the find algorithm.